# Sizing ScrollPane inside a BorderLayout properly in javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I can't get my scroll pane to properly show the information that I want to with the proper scroll bar. I'm putting an HBox which contains two VBoxes into a ScrollPane and inserting that ScrollPane as the center element of a BorderLayout. It seems like the ScrollPane ignores the bounds of the window and becomes so large that using a scroll bar is unnecessary and I can't view the bottom content. I've tried wrapping it in an AnchorPane and setting the bounds of the AnchorPane which didn't work, I've tried setting the size manually which kind of worked but led to some odd glitches where content would show up all over the screen, I've tried wrapping it in a Pane which I then added to the center, I've tried wrapping the HBox in a VBox before adding it to the ScrollPane and then wrapping the ScrollPane in a Pane, and I've tried various uses of the setFitToHeight/Width functions. I just want it to pay attention to the bounds of the window and conform accordingly

edit: some example code

```
VBox vbox1 = getvbox1Content();//this is long thus requires a scrollpane
VBox vbox2 = getvbox2Content();
HBox hbox = new HBox();
hbox.getChildren().addAll(vbox1, vbox2);
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
scrollPane.setContent(hbox);
borderPane.setCenter(scrollPane);
```

Comment: Hello, im not a javafx expert but example code would make this easier. Can you provide example code for your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JohnMercier I'm not sure it helps much without the specific code which would make it too long to be helpful but hopefully that clarifies it somewhat

Comment: Unfortunately, your example is neither _complete_ (cannot be copy-pasted and executed) nor is it _verifiable_ (by virtue of it not being complete). If your real code is too long or too complex then create another project that has only the necessary components to reproduce the problem (i.e. a _minimal_ example). _Mock any data or content._ If the `ScrollPane` is growing to fit the dimensions of its content, that is odd indeed; however, without a proper [mcve] it's difficult to help diagnose the problem.